# Django - import model from another project

Tags: django, model

I've never done such thing so i'm not sure what would be the best approach for solving this problem:

I have two Django projects:

```
root/
    project1/
            manage.py
            project1/
                    models.py
                    urls.py
                    ...
    project2/
            manage.py
            project2/
                    models.py
                    urls.py
                    ...
```

Those projects use same database, they have around 10 models (database tables) each and some of the models overlap: Project1 needs ForeignKey from one fo the Project2's models, but also Project2 needs ForeignKey from one of the Project1's models:

Project1:

```
class Area_model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Question_model(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    answer = models.SmallIntegerField()
    ...
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee_model)
```

Project2:

```
class Employee_model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area_model)
```

I tried to import project1.models into project2's models.py but it says 'unknown module'. I need to import project1 to project2 and reverse, is that going to be a problem? (circular reference?)
If so, how can i accomplish this in some other way?

Comment: Why does it need to be to different projects? Why don't you just make the two reusable apps instead?

Comment: Reusable apps, I like that. Apps should be packaged inside a python package and be installables, maybe by using `pip`, or by running `python setup.py install`.

Comment: Here https://github.com/slackmart/tastypie-sepomex one example, explore the `setup.py`.

Comment: Those projects are two totally different websites, under different domains. (they have separate templates, stylesheets, urls.py, views.py etc.). I've never made reusable apps before, so i don't know if it's possible to use it in this case?

Comment: it look like microservices ?

Answer (score 3):

In your WSGI.py, add the path of your second project to the sys.path by `sys.path.append('/root')`.

In your settings.py of the first project, add `'project2.app2'` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` list:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'app1',
    'project2.app2',
    ...
]
```

And then you should be able to easily import the models of your second project by using `from project2.project2.models import *`

At least that is how it worked for me.

Comment: This response was a big help for me. However, I needed to add the "sys.path.append('/root')" to my settings.py file as it appears to me that the installed apps are processed before  WSGI.py

Comment: Hey @Andrea and @Paul West, I know this answer was posted a while ago but I'm running into an issue when trying to apply this solution. I get the following error
`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`
Do you know why this error occurs and how it could be fixed?

Comment: You will need to post some code to get some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the path of the other project to your PYTHONPATH and then adding the app of the first project to settings.py installed apps of second project.
Do not forget to import the app first and you will have to import the models of the first app in models.py of the second app. I am not sure if it will work as I have not tested it but you may give it a try.